# FlatList does not render any text in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm fairly new to react native and redux and was trying to render the library title from a JSON file in a flat list using redux, but my `FlatList` component does not render anything on the screen. 
here's my code :

**LibraryList.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { FlatList } from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import ListItem from "./ListItem";

class LibraryList extends Component {

  renderItem(library) {
    return <ListItem library={library} />;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={this.props.libraries}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        keyExtractor={library => library.id}
      />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { libraries: state.libraries };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LibraryList);
```

**ListItem.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";
import { CardSection } from "./common";

class ListItem extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <CardSection>
        <Text>{this.props.library.title}</Text>
      </CardSection>
    );
  }
}
export default ListItem;
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import reducers from "./reducers";
import { Header } from "./components/common";
import LibraryList from "./components/LibraryList";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
      <View>
        <Header headerText="Tech Stack" />
        <LibraryList />
      </View>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The JSON file is like

```
[
    {
        "id": '' ,
        "title": '' ,
        "description":''
    },
    {
        "id":'' ,
        "title":'' ,
        "description":''
    }
]
```

I read some solutions for this suggesting changing the `renderItem` function to something like this

```
renderItem = ({ library }) => <ListItem library={library} />
```

still does not work. Can someone help me with this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: try to ```console.log``` the value of ```this.props.libraries``` inside  your ```LibraryList.js```

Answer (score 2):

You have to make your `renderItem` as an arrow function. Otherwise you have to bind your function inside constructor in order to access function as `renderItem={this.renderItem}`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ListItem from './ListItem';

class LibraryList extends Component {

    renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        return <ListItem library={item} />
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <FlatList
                data={this.props.libraries}
                renderItem={this.renderItem}
                keyExtractor={library => library.id}
            />
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { libraries: state.libraries };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LibraryList);
```

or you can call your `renderItem` as an [arrow function inside render](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#arrow-function-in-render) like below

```
renderItem={(item) => this.renderItem(item)}
```

but using an arrow function in render creates a new function each time the component renders, which may break optimizations based on strict identity comparison.

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Answer (score 1):

In your flatlist try thi s:

```
<FlatList
             data={this.props.libraries}
 renderItem={({item, index}) => {
            this.renderItems(item); // change this name to renderItems so that it doesnt clash with flatlist default renderItem
          }}

/>
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: I tried this but it still only shows the header and nothing else.

Comment: The only thing missing in this solution is return behind this.renderItems

Answer (score 1):

You have several approaches to your problem.

Firstly your renderItem should be binded, so either do this

```
renderItem = (library) => {
```

or this

```
renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
```

besides the binding problem, flatlist prop renderItem will return to your function an object with this structure

```
{ item, index }
```

so in reality your renderItem should be like this

```
renderItem({ item }){
    return <ListItem library={item} />;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help but still nothing seems to work.

Comment: @Icebreaker as in it doesn't render or something else? Put some console.logs on your ListItem render to see the props or something. Is your state.libraries even populated with data?